# Create Node.js calendar stream

Tags: node.js, api, calendar, caldav

I've written an application with Angular11 front-end, node.js MicroService back-end and mongoDB. My back-end is hosted on DigitalOcean. This application is about booking dates with blue collars (e.g. therapists).

I want to create a feature that the therapists can add a calendar (like calDAV) to their phones.

When a Client books a date online it should automatically sync (or in polling depends on the phone sync settings) the new booking to the therapist's phonecalendar (of course only his/her dates). Read-only would be enough for now.

I've been googling for hours now to find a way to implement this calendar stream, but for now it's really bad for me. Is it possible that nobody has ever wanted this before or am I doing it the wrong way?

For me a JavaScript-written service would me perfect because I know JavaScript well, but I am also open to using other technologies.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a calendar service that users. I am actually building something quite similar to this. Calendars usually look data from the links you provide at intervals quite automatically. What I propose on doing is:

- Use express an API end where you can send UID for users in query.
- This API could serve ics or a stream.

For calendar data generation you could use `datebook` which does most of the things for you!